# Using Hadoop to perform DML operations on large fixed-format files

Tags: database, file-io, hadoop

We have a product that uses a MySQL database as the data-store. The data-store holds large amount of data. The problem we are facing is that the response time of the application is very slow. The database queries are very basic with very simple joins, if any. The root cause for the slow response time according to some senior employees is the database operations on the huge data-store.

Another team in our company had worked on a project in the past where they processed large fixed-format files using Hadoop and dumped the contents of these files into database tables. Borrowing from this project, some of the team members feel that we can migrate from using a MySQL database to simple fixed-format files that will hold the data instead. There will be one file corresponding to each table in the database instead. We can then build another data interaction layer that provides interfaces for performing DML operations on the contents in these files. This layer will be developed using Hadoop and the MapReduce programming model.

At this point, several questions come to my mind. 
1. Does the problem statement fit into the kind of problems that are solved using Hadoop?
2. How will the application ask the data interaction layer to fetch/update/delete the required data? As far as my understanding goes, the files containing the data will reside on HDFS. We will spawn a Hadoop job that will process the required file (similar to a table in the db) and fetch the required data. This data will be written to an outout file on HDFS. We will have to parse this file to get the required content. 
3. Will the approach of using fixed format-files and processing them with Hadoop truly solve the problem?

I have managed to set up a simple node cluster with two Ubuntu machines but after playing around with Hadoop for a while, I feel that the problem statement is not a good fit for Hadoop. I could be completely wrong and therefore want to know whether Hadoop fits into this scenario or is it just a waste of time as the problem statement is not in line with what Hadoop is meant for?

Comment: Can't you just denormalize your tables so you don't have to perform these joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest go straight to Hive (http://hive.apache.org/). It is SQL engine / datawarehouse build on top of the Hadoop MR. 
In a nutshell - it get Hadoop scalability and hadoop high latency. 
I would consider storing bulk of data there, do all required transformation and only summarized data move to MySQL to serve queries. Usually it is not good idea to translate user requests to the hive queries - they are too slow, capability to run jobs in parallel is not trivial.

Comment: What if I have simple select queries with rarely any joins or group by required? Can I directly translate user requests to the hive query?

Comment: Yep, Hive supports big part of the standard SQL operations. It is in particular good with group by's since they maps very naturally to MapReduce. Equ-joins are also supported. What is not supported is joins by conditions different then = , because it is something hard to map to MapReduce.

Comment: I ran a basic select query with a simple where condition on a table with 3 columns and 10K records and it took hive 20 seconds to fetch the result. I ran this on a single machine (pseudo-distributed mode). Any idea how I can optimize the query execution time? I tried increasing the number of mappers in mapred-site.xml using mapred.map.tasks for hadoop but hive seems to have ignored this and it uses a single mappper.

Comment: as long as you have only one small file - hive can not use many mappers. I would suggest to put 3-5 GB in number of files to see the effect. Shuffling time also is not realistic without actual network.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to update data more often then storing directly in  hadoop may not be a good option for you. To update a file in hadoop you may have to rewrite the file and then delete old file and  copy a new file in hdfs.

However if you are just searching and joining the data then its good option. If you use hive then you could make some queries like sql.

In hadoop your work flow could be something described below:

1. You will run a hadoop job for your queries.
2. Your hadoop program will parse query and execute some job to join
   and read files based on your queries and input parameters.
3. Your output will be generated in hdfs.
4. You will copy the output to local file system. Then show the output to your program.